# CKfinder can't show up filebrowser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckfinder

After trying to setup ckfinder 3.3 into ckeditor and failed many times. I always got this error.
[image]

Then, I try to read some article about this prolem, remove obj folder, clean solution and rebuilt, merge web.config files,v.v....it still happens to me. After that, I try remove all

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

In web.config files, I got a new error with no meaning:
[image]

It took me the whole day and I still confused about this, does cksource really test it before release the product? I am so confused right now. I dont know what I have to do to make it works. Sorry about my bad English and thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you trying to run sample WebApp application or are you doing some custom integration?

Comment: Hello @kfazi, both of them got the same errors

Comment: The error caused by `authentication mode="None"` will be gone if you convert CKFinder to application (as described in [docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html#quickstart_installation_zip)). However this error with binary contents looks very weird and I'm not sure what may be wrong. Are you upgrading from CKFinder 2.x?